# Remove render-blocking JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am developing a web in angularjs. there are approx 42 javascript files which i have to load. Google PageSpeed Insight ask to remove Remove render-blocking JavaScript.

```
    <script async src="path to file"></script>
```

it load files asyn but jquery.js file loading after files which need jquery file.i am stuck because site taking a lot of time to load.Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Not to answer your actual question but creating a bundle for those 42 files (I use gulp) helps to improve site performance on loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be long answer about different ways to implement that (using modules and http://requirejs.org/ or https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), but TL;DR - **try to put jQuery script call inside the head tag of your webpage**, while the others scripts in bottom of html page.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, i am new with angularjs. can you share a piece of code or any link of code example. i am not getting require.js. thanks

Comment: Code examples are here: http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html, but it will take effort to update each file in your project to make RequireJS modular approach to work. May be that's not the case for you? Just using CDN and put jQuery on top of the page is much faster way to improve site loading performance

Answer (score 0):

Found [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/id_UBdtzFew/ZUIz_ZeFc-4J) which helps to address the pagespeed insights "problem" and improves (in my opinion) the UX. Here is Sander's suggestion:

```
<div ng-if="false">
  <h1>Loading the application, please hold on</h1>
  <div class='aCssSpinner'</div>
</div>
```