# Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content (Angular JS Controllers)

Tags: angularjs, seo, mean-stack

I am trying to optimize my page speed with me MEAN stack application. I have run into the issue where I should be eliminating the render-blocking Javascript and CSS. I have gotten to the point where I have almost eliminated everything, EXCEPT for the controllers that have to be loaded.

I am thinking that it is not possible to actually do this, since angular throws an injector module error when I place "async" as an attribute on the `<script>`.

I was also thinking of making one large controller, but that does not really work as well.

The link to the site is https://coastalreign.com, below is the code for the controllers:

```js
<!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/MainCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ContactCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ProductCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ProductsCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/CartCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/TrackOrderCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/CheckoutCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/DesignerCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/SublimationCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/LocationCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ServiceAreaCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/CategoriesCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/getCategoryText.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/CustomQuoteCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/GradContestCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/four04Ctrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/popularGroupingCtrl.js"></script>
```

Thank you in advance for your guy's expertise!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove render-blocking JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522390/remove-render-blocking-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the amount of requests. I would bundle the JS files (app + vendor files) and minify them.
You can check for performance tips with Chrome - Developer tools - audits

Answer (score 0):

You can use gulp-concat to reduce the amount of requests as Alexander's answer suggested. Then you can use gulp-minify to decrease the size of the file. You will have some additional issues if you want to put async option because you might need to render HTML which depends on angular